# Multiple Filters with ng-bind-html In Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can we use multiple filters with `ng-bind-html`?

I have two filters. One is custom filter, I called it `linkyHashes` and other is [ngsanitize linky](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky) filters.

I use this filter by

```
<div class="mts mbs lg-feed-content-txt" ng-bind-html="activity.post.text | linkyhashes | linky : '_blank'"></div>
```

But my custom filter do not works, only linky filter works

This is my custom filter

```
LinkagoalWebApp.filter('linkyhashes' ,['$filter', '$sce',  function($filter, $sce){
    return function(text, target){
        if (!text) return text;
         var replacedText = $filter('linky')(text, target);
         var targetAttr = "";
         if (angular.isDefined(target)) {
         targetAttr = ' target="' + target + '"';
         }

        // replace #hashtags
        var replacePattern = /(?:#)([a-zA-Z|_\d]+)/ig;
        replacedText = text.replace(replacePattern, '<a class="hashtag" href="http://linkagoal.local/tagged/$1"' + targetAttr + '>#$1</a>');
        $sce.trustAsHtml(replacedText);
        return replacedText;
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that problem by changing ng-bind-html

```
ng-bind-html="activity.post.text | linkyhashes | linky : '_blank'"
```

to

```
ng-bind-html=" activity.post.text | linky : '_blank' | linkyhashes "
```

and in the filter I remove  `$filter('linky')(text, target);`