# Apply Multiple filter on ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have to apply three different kind of filter in same time.
My data is coming with some URL, so what i need to do that just highlight the URL and make it clickable.

**Filter 1**: This is for HTML data

```
.filter('filterHtml',function($sce){
    return function(input){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
})
```

**Filter 2**: If any URL open in IN APP browser

```
.filter('hrefToJS', function ($sce, $sanitize) {
    return function (text) {
        var regex = /href="([\S]+)"/g;
        var newString = $sanitize(text).replace(regex, "onClick=\"window.open('$1', '_blank', 'location=yes')\"");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(newString);
    } 
});
```

**Filter 3**: For highliting URL

```
$filter('linky')(text, target, attributes)
```

I tried like this

```
 <p ng-bind-html="t.text| linky:'_blank' | hrefToJS | filterHtml"></p>
```

But two filter is working while pushing third one, not working. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985595/multiple-filters-with-ng-bind-html-in-angularjs) link

Comment: There is a bracket "]" at the end, I don't think that should be there.

Comment: that was mistake in post

Comment: Do you have any error ? https://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate the issue ?

Comment: I dont have control on data, so creating fiddle is difficult.

Comment: can we merge 'filterHtml' and 'hrefToJS' filter in one

Comment: You could have only one filter from those three. The idea behind having 3 filters instead of one, is that you can use them separately somewhere else.